# Menu padding Issue since FireFox 4

Tags: html, css, firefox, menu

I've checked other questions on here but I haven't found anything that will help me.

Since FireFox 4 was released I've been having an issue with the menu on my website.

www.ffxivinfo.com

As you can see, the menu is supposed to fit along the little graphic buttons so that each link is on the "button". In Chrome, IE8 (not checked 9) and FireFox 3.5 this looked perfect. However since FireFox 4 it has been displaying wrong.

It looks like it's a padding issue but I can't figure out where it is coming from. I have even removed the padding between each link so that they are close together (0 padding) yet the menu still stretches further to the right in FireFox 4+ than in other browsers.

I use the auto generated menus available at purecssmenu.com and I modified it to fit my own website.

Here is a link to just the nav code, I use a PHP include to insert it.
http://www.ffxivinfo.com/nav.php

And here is a link to the CSS for it.
http://www.ffxivinfo.com/navstyle.css

Basically I need the navigation to look the same in all browsers so that it fits into the graphic "buttons". I'm tempted to just scrap the current design and go with a simple gradient background and leave the menu wider in FireFox 4+ than other browsers but that's a bit defeatist.

Any help would be much appreciated. This is the first time a coding problem has sent me to a forum asking for help but I just can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not in your margins but due to the differences in text rendering between the browsers.  In this case, Firefox is rendering the text slightly wider.

If I might suggest an alternative, rather than using an image background and hoping for pixel-perfect rendering (which is pretty unlikely given the diversity of browsers and operating systems out there) try styling the links themselves with background-color and border-radius.

Comment: Wow I was unaware border-radius even existed. I'm not familiar with all the CSS3 features yet. I could chop out so much code with that trying to hack rounded corners with CSS2 for my headers. I like that alternative but I'd still like to find a solution because the set of links appears too wide for the space available in FireFox when they're spread out like that and a user is logged in (different links in menu).

Comment: As I said, I think your core issue is due to text rendering differences.  Try using `background-color` for the links instead of an image for the entire row.  `border-radius` would allow you to have rounded corners on most modern browsers will a fall back of having a square background for older browsers (an acceptable fallback in most scenarios).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem in FF6. However, I see you specify your font size in pt. pt is for print, not the web. Try changing that to px and see if that fixes your situation.

Comment: That's strange. It appears in FF6 for me, and has in all versions since FF4. http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/6707/ff6menu.jpg Does px vs pt really matter that much? I can give it a try.

Comment: I tried changing the pt font sizes to px in a non-live version of the site for testing. It makes it look better but it's still wrong. When in px, it's like each link is one pixel wider than in Chrome. So by the time you get to the last link it's about 10 pixels to the right. Sure I could change the image to account for that but then it's wrong in Chrome and presumably IE9. I guess I could just live with that and use the border-radius I discovered thanks to ajsharma. I don't even think CSS3 was in use when I built this site. I am curious why it looks fine in yours/other people's FF6's however.

Answer (score 0):

I might ignore the Firefox 4 issue.

FF is now on version 6.

Your issue does not appear in FF3.5 (the most widely used FF) or FF6, both of which have more browser share than FF4.

http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201008-201108-bar

Comment: Hmm..  I was going on what the others had to say re no issues with FF6.